# Error 407 Authentication Required on Windows Server 2008 for webclient.download()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a SSIS package and a Script Task on **Windows Server 2008 R2**. This Script Task downloads the file

```
 System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
 string webResource = varCollection["User::RemoteUri"].Value.ToString();
 string fileName = varCollection["User::SourcePath"].Value.ToString() + "filename.csv";
     myWebClient.DownloadFile(webResource, fileName);
```

**Working Test Case:-** 
1. If I execute this SSIS package from Visual Studio, then it successfully downloads this file. Here Important note is Im not sending any type of authentication.

**Failing Use case:-**
1. If I call this SSIS package from SQL Server Agent Job, then this SSIS package fails to download the file and gives following error

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address<c/> String fileName)
```

I'm struggling this issue from last two days, please help me.
This is very important to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Ashok, Have you check this issue with network department(if any). Its more like a network security issue. I think the FireWall rule needs to be relaxed.

Comment: Asif, thanks for your response. But, I can download if I run SSIS package through Visual Studio. Still do I need to check with network department??

Comment: I think yes, if you check this issue with your network team and ask him to give you administrator rights.

Comment: Do you mean to say that, the owner of SQL Job should have Admin rights?

Comment: Ok, I wil try that one. Thanks for your help.